# set gps on without showing dialogue

Tags: android

After searching deeply , I am able to on gps using dialogue box when app is resume.I used following code which i found on google.

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);//Setting priotity of Location request to high
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);//5 sec Time interval for location update
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient to show dialog always when GPS is off

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    updateGPSStatus("GPS is Enabled in your device");
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is working properly.
But i want to on gps without showing this dialogue box.How can I solve this?

Comment: It's not possible at this time to enable/disable gps without user interaction except if you have rooted device

Comment: it is not up to you to choose whenever user wants to turn his GPS on. You can't and shouldn't be able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i want to on gps without showing this dialogue box

There is no possible LEGAL way to do it, as that would be a major privacy flow. Maybe on rooted phone you might be able to do it, (I'm not sure about that although, but sometime back I read some article about this on some forum.) But android doesn't allow to turn on GPS without user's intervention.

Either you give user option to go to settings menu from where they can enable GPS (old school way), or use `GoogleApiClient` to enable GPS on single click like google maps.